# Node select on load and make href work together

Tags: jquery, jstree

Can I make *work node select on load* and *make href* work together? Now I get an infinity loop and the page always refreshes. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrayCollection = <%=GetJson()%>;
    var selectedid = <%=GetSelected()%>;

    $('#jstree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': arrayCollection,
        }
    })
    .on('loaded.jstree', function () {
        $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', selectedid);
    })
    .on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        document.location = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true).children('a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you throw a jsfiddle example up?

Comment: I can't, external resources 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page to which you're redirecting has this javascript on it. It will loop infinitely. On load it's going to reload the tree, select the node and redirect to the selected node.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrayCollection = <%=GetJson()%>;
    var selectedid = <%=GetSelected()%>;
    $('#jstree')
                .jstree({
                    'core': {
                        'data': arrayCollection,
                    }
                }
                )
                .on('loaded.jstree', function () {
                    $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', selectedid);
                })
                .on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                    var newLoc = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true).children('a').attr('href');
                    //only redirect if the current location doesn't match the redirect location
                    if(window.location.href != newLoc){
                        document.location = newLoc;
                    }
                });
  });
```